# Magento 1.9 header and footer missing

Tags: themes, magento-1.9, updates

I've made a Magento update from 1.7 to 1.9 and now my homepage is missing the header and footer sections. The homepage now only shows the slider and the blog section and a widget. Interesting is that if i go url/home it will show the entire CMS page with header and footer, but without the slider and the blog section.

In the configuration i have not made any changes at all 
(Default settings)
Default Web URL: cms
CMS Home Page: Grand Home
Default No-route URL: cms/index/noRoute
CMS No Route Page: Page Not Found

(Store settings)
All set as default

(Store view)
Same as the default

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. The theme is custom made and instead of the developers using the backend dashboard for a custom theme inside the Design of CMS pages they used the theme layout cms.xml .On of the widget ID was wrong and it made the header and footer not to display.